# Selenium pytest vs nunit

Tags: automated-testing, nunit

I'from background of automated testing with tools like Testcomplete, QTP, JMeter and soupUI.

Recently there was a need automation of web-application for institute I work. I started with Selenium-Python. all good but Selenium doesn't provide reporting facility.

Hence included python-unittest to support reporting.. But it doesn't provide test dependency. "**Sorry folks, I have had enough preaching........ *test-dependency is tooo bad***  "

So instead of unittest I tried pytest But came across a problem [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44418135/python-use-pytest-to-test-test-methods-written-in-subclass)

So pytest also seems bit odd in OOP (compared to unittest)- pl let me know if I'm wrong.

My next option would be going after C#.
Do nunit provide easy way of provide test dependency and inheritance?

Comment: Why do you need test dependencies? Without that information it's hard to give you a reasonable answer.

Comment: Seems like XY problem: you are asking about X because you think it will help you to solve Y. What is your real problem you are trying to solve or avoid? Both Pytest and Pyunit are widely used and popular, how is your specific problem different?

Comment: @Kate my test suite will be going to have some incremental test. eg if A is success B should be run.

Comment: So the successful completion of A is a prerequisite for B? You don't need to make that a dependency: make it part of the setup instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have described test-dependency is really more to do with how your run your test suites.

If you group your testcases into suites then you can have your CI system run them as jobs triggering from each other. I would definitely avoid trying to build this into the scripts as it will make it hard to run them standalone if you need to.

In terms of output from tests i would advise you don't stray from xunit output as there a plenty of mature tools that can display and manage test results in this format.  Nunit output is tricky and not as many tools exist for it, or at least not free ones. I allways advise not using compiled languages for test unless they are unit tests, anything above that layer should by language agnostic and use the public interfaces and services.

Comment: thanks for valuable advice. why do you advice... "not using compiled languages for test "... after much research Java with TestNG is appealing for me.

Comment: Finally decided to go for Java with TestNG [ToolsQA](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-introduction/) has very good tutorials you can be up and running fairly quickly

Comment: Compiled languages can't be used in an interactive shells . I find these shells really useful for using your test framework to drive the product in exploratory tests. With a compiled language you have to get far more of the code working up front before your tests work, you also get less helpful error messages. That said go with what you can code in best.